# how set a initial/default item in menu button?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm looking at the [config options](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.button.Cycle) for a menu button and don't see one to set the initial/default item in the menu when it's first rendered. Did I miss it? How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `checked:true` You can move it to the other option to see it working.